# Telnetlib, bytestrings, and "invalid escape sequence"

Tags: python, regex, string, expect, telnetlib

I'm using `telnetlib.expect()` to interface with a device that responds in bytestrings, apparently. Unless I use bytestrings in the regex passed to `expect()` (either precompiled, or literals), an exception is generated: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. However, `pycodestyle` complains this is `W605 invalid escape sequence '\d'`, and further reading makes me think this will become a Python syntax error in the future.

In summary:

```
telnetlib.expect([b'\d']) # OK, but W065
telnetlib.expect(['\d'] # TypeError
telnetlib.expect([r'\d'] # TypeError
```

Is there a way through this, or is pycodestyle simply wrong?

(BTW, can't seem to suppress the W065 in pycodestyle, other than suppressing all warnings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytestring literals use `\` as an escape character the same way string literals do. So similar to them you have to either use a raw bytestring literal `rb'\d'` or use double backslash `b'\\d'`.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

> In plain English: Both types of literals can be enclosed in matching
>   single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`). They can also be enclosed in
>   matching groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally
>   referred to as triple-quoted strings). The backslash (`\`) character is
>   used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such
>   as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.